# Can not display grid uniformly

Tags: javascript, html, grid

I want to generate a grid based on 2 dimensions given as inputs.I want to then provide a means to update the grid cells by sending an object : 
`updateCell={index1,index2,value}`

When i use the below code the attributes :`grid-column` ,`grid-row` of the cells are not set accordingly.

```js
function getCellId(row, col) {
    var name = "cell_" +  row + "_" +  col ;
    return name;
}

//entrypoint
function initGrid(rowSize, colSize) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("mygrid");
    for (i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            var data = {
                rowSize: rowSize,
                colSize: colSize,
                row: i,
                col: j
            };
            var cell = initCell(data);
            grid.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

}
function initCell(data) {

    var cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.id = window.getCellId(data.row, data.col);
    cell.innerHTML = "NotComputed";


    cell.style["grid-column"] = data.row.toString() + "/" + data.rowSize.toString();
    cell.style["grid-row"] = data.col.toString() + "/" + data.colSize.toString();
    return cell; 
}
```

```css
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grid.css" />
    <script src="grid.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            window.initGrid(2,2); //the 2 inputs
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container" id="mygrid">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was  that i was using the attributes `grid-column` and `grid-row` when setting the `style` of the cells.

I solved it by using `grid-column-start`,`grid-column-end`,`grid-row-start`,`grid-row-end`.

```
function initCell(data) {

    var cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.id = window.getCellId(data.row, data.col);
    cell.innerHTML = "NotComputed";

    cell.style["grid-row-start"]=data.row;
    cell.style['grid-row-end']=data.row+1;
    cell.style['grid-column-start']=data.col;
    cell.style['grid-column-end']=data.col+1;

    return cell;

}
```